# EpicEditor: editor.preview() remove cursor from another form element

Tags: javascript, cursor, focus, preview, epiceditor

I have a input field when I placed focus and then trying to load epiceditor on a textarea and try to set preview mode. So preview mode working prefect, but the problem is it removed the cursor from the text field.

Is there a way to load epiceditor and set preview mode and cursor stay on the input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
editor.on('preview', function () {
  $(editor.getElement('previewer')).find('input').focus();
});
```

The previous code runs each time preview is opened. It then gets the preview iframes body then lastly finds the first input and focuses

Comment: Ok sounds great. I have tried it in some other way and that's resolved my issue. Anyway I'll try this one. Thanks!